# Python create an SDK instead just an API

Tags: python, sdk, django-rest-framework

I have a project developed in python/django, i create my API interface for public a view of the db to my clients using POST GET and others calls, all done.

Now i'am wondering what is the best way to create a real SDK for my program, i mean the possibility for my clients, using specific calls, to make my enviroment execute something and return result from their code.
Are there some tools, like for example Django REST framework for the API, also for SDKs?

Thanks at all in advance

Comment: Maybe check out https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API is server side while SDK is client side.

For example, you can provide APIs using python/django. But your customers can use nodejs, C++, C#, JAVA... anything they want to communicate with your server.

If you provide a SDK for C++, that's just for C++ customers. For JAVA customers, you still need to provide another SDK for JAVA.

So in short, you cannot find a cross-language-sdk-generator.